# Automatically Fill & Match Email Input Based on First and Last Name Value

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I'm using the Chrome extension "Autofill/Autoclick". How can I make it so that email address inputs are autofilled based on the values of first and last name. There is a Chrome extension, "Form Filler" that is able to achieve this, but there is no way to see how it does the input matching.

I've tried playing around with some regex code but only to get nowhere.

For example:

First Name: John            Last Name: Smith

I would like for the email address input to display a randomized email address but include the first and last name values. Such as:

Email Address: John.Smith@gmail.com

I would also like to have randomized numbers on the end of the email address like this:

Email Address: John.Smith99@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Takes your first and last name as input and generates email adress with random numbers.

```js
$("#fname, #lname").on('input', function() {
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    $("#mail").attr("value", fname + "." + lname + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10) + "@gmail.com");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<input id="fname" placeholder="First name" type="text">
<input id="lname" placeholder="Last name" type="text">

<input id="mail" type="email">
</body>
</html>
```